# Is there any way to validate a foreign key using Laravel's Validation syntax?

Tags: php, validation, laravel

Say I have an `object` which relates to a `mission`. Users can upload objects and say that it has a relationship with one of these missions. Is there anyway to check that the `mission_id` that the user has selected for this object actually exists in this database using Laravel's `Validation` class and rules?

This way, I can check that `mission_id` is not only an integer, but also exists in the database.

For example, I guess I'm looking for something like:

```
$rules = array(
    'mission_id' => 'foreignKeyExistsInMissions|integer'
)
```

Where `foreignKeyExistsInMissions` is the validation rule I'm looking for.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This should work:

```
'mission_id' => 'required|exists:missions,id',
```

And the message:

```
'mission_id.exists' => 'Not an existing ID',
```

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-exists) (v4.2 docs)

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-exists) (v5.5 docs)

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-exists) (v7.x docs)

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-exists) (v8.x docs)

Comment: Not quite sure how you're doing validation, but [this](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-error-messages) goes over custom error messages (same linked-to doc page as above, though a little farther down)

Comment: works in 5.5 though doesn't appear to be documeneted.

Comment: but if relation to the another database my laravel this cant find out where is this relation

Answer (score 1):

`'mission_id' => 'required|exists:missions,id',`
missions is the table name and id is the referenced column name on mission table
 `''mission_id' => 'required|exists:table_name,referenced_column',`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Leave\LeaveAssigns;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class StoreLeaveAssignRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'role_id' => ['required', Rule::exists('roles', 'id')]
        ];
    }
}
```